# check if data are double, float or half float

Tags: floating-point

I wonder if there's a way to check if a number of binary data contain doubles, floats or half floats.

For half float I'm using the code below to convert back to float:

```
fltInt32 = ((fltInt16 & 0x8000) << 16) \
           | ((fltInt16 & 0x7fff) << 13) + 0x38000000;
```

Comment: In C/C++, variables of type double contain double-precision floating-point numbers; type float is for single-precision floating-point and there is nothing standard known as half-float. Provide more explanations.

Comment: Do you have information about the range of numbers? All except possibly some of the all-exponent-bits-one patterns are used in both float and double, but different patterns are used for the most commonly used magnitude ranges.

Comment: The binary data are vertices, I know they are always float or half, but have to check them visually, instead I'd like to know if there's some *probability* check I can use to guess (I was thinking about invalid floats/half) (about doubles just curiosity)

Comment: @Alex There is not invalid float, but there are NaN values. If you know that your data is not supposed to contain any NaNs, what appears to be one would be a clue that you are using the wrong format.

Comment: Zero is going to present a serious problem, if it is a possible value. I don't think there is any way to distinguish two half-width zeros from one float zero. It may require global understanding of the file format. If 90% of the words fall into an expected magnitude range if assumed to be float, assume they are all float.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan thank you for both your comments, data are vertices for a 3D model, zero may be present but rare. I'll collect some information as you suggested based on samples selected *visually*, to check if I can use some pattern (contained values that make sense)

Comment: @PascalCuoq thank you, isNaN cut off about 50%~ of 4200~ models, still I know float are only about 80~.

Comment: As a simple, less bit-twiddling, approach I suggest interpreting each word as a float and as two half-floats. Test whether it is a number (rather than NaN) and of reasonable magnitude regarded as a float, and do the same for the half-float interpretation.